# Connect Arduino to a Processing program

Tags: arduino, processing, arduino-uno

This is my first time working with an Arduino and with Processing. I am trying to get them to connect with the following code, but I keep receiving an error about ports (*"Error opening serial port ... Port busy"*):

#### Arduino

```cpp
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println("Hello, World!");
    delay(100);
}
```

#### Processing

```java
import processing.serial.*;

Serial myPort;
String val;

void setup(){
  String portName = Serial.list()[0];
  myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
}

void draw()
{
  if ( myPort.available() > 0) {
    val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');
  }
  println(val); //print it out in the console
}
```

Error:

[image]

In Arduino I have set the port to *usbModem1411* (Arduino Uno).

I feel like I have to change the port somewhere in processing but I am not sure if that's the solution or how to change it in Processing.

P.S. I am using a ROBO YourDuino

I am using this tutorial's information: *[Connecting Arduino to Processing](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/connecting-arduino-to-processing)*

I can change the Serial.list()[0]; to 1 and 5, but it will print null, if I change to any other number, I receive similar errors to the one above.

I get errors if I change the

[image]

[image]

Comment: as they mentioned try 0,1,2,3,4,...: `String portName = Serial.list()[0]; //change the 0 to a 1 or 2 , 3, 4 .. etc. to match your port`

Comment: @houssam Port 1 and 5 are the only one's that don't throw errors, but those print null.

Comment: getting one or two **nulls** is not problem as they mentioned: [here](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/4/4/6/9/4/51ae08bace395f6f1b000000.png) , are you sure that the Arduino code  is being executed?

Comment: I am clicking verify, then upload, and then serial monitor. Then I go over to processing and click Run. Is that correct? @houssam

Comment: yes correct, don't forget to choose the board type and the port : (https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-arduino-ide) _If you’re not sure which serial device is your Arduino, take a look at the available ports (in the menu), then unplug your Arduino and look again. The one that disappeared is your Arduino._

Comment: @houssam I have tried that. I attached the images in the original post, is that not the correct way?

Comment: I think you have problem somewhere; is this the first time you run Arduino? you should see `/dev/tty.usbmodem` not `/dev/cu.usbmodem` .try to press erase [link](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,142550.0.html)? you may need to install driver [link](http://superuser.com/q/547046/214926)

Comment: @houssam I tried both of those, i still don't see /dev/tty.usbmodem

Answer (score 0):

So, you have problem in connecting your Arduino to the computer, not in the Processing program.

Try to use another USB port in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You get the "Port busy" error, because you have the serial monitor window opened from Arduino IDE.

Try not to open the serial monitor window when you connect to Processing via serial communication.